# how to get the propertyNames from a feature without the system properties?

Tags: google-earth-engine

When dealing with a GEE features, I can get the name of my columns by calling `propertyNames` method.

Problem is that this method also include all the system properties that are often irrelevant.

How can I split them?

Here is a small example:

```py
fc = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2")
feat = fc.first()
columns = feat.propertyNames()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove the system properties:

```
names = feat.propertyNames().aside(print)
other = names.removeAll(feat.select(["system:.*"]).propertyNames())
```

Comment: I tried your solution in the code editor and it failed. Multiple things that might be wrong here: the system properties are starting with "system:" and the List object have no "select" method. I posted another answer based on filter that use the same logic and don't raise error.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up classes a little.  Fixed the example.  (There's several other ways as well, including going through a dictionary, which does support `select` and `remove`)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@Noel Gorelick](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/90192/noel-gorelick) I can filter out the system properties:

```py
names = feat.propertyNames()
system = names.filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith("item", "system:")) 
columns = names.filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith("item", "system:").Not())
```

Note: for javascripts users, "Not" should be replaced by "not"